# VSCode keeps opening new Python window every 10 seconds or so, unprompted, but still says Python not installed and am unable to use terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode to learn python and algorithms, and it has usually worked great until a couple of days ago when I had to reinstall due to some reason. Now **every time I open VSCode, python windows keep opening up and then it still says python not installed**. I have tried reinstalling both python and VSCode, installing a different version of python, different version of python extension for VSCode, none of it solves the problem for long. It does however briefly stop when I reinstall python and everything works as normal, including the terminal for running the code. But then in a few minutes it randomly starts opening new python windows and the terminal also breaks.

Screenshots I have captured:

- Python windows opening [ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q5CD.png)
- Python not installed error [ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVwnY.png)

Nothing happens when I run my code via the terminal (please ignore the actual code, it is a work in progress and I got interrupted by this error) [ss3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqLQI.png)

UPDATE 1: Since I was unable to fix the issue, I decided to make a new user profile and that fixed the problem in that particular profile, but the original one still has this problem. Maybe that can help someone figure out what the issue is.

UPDATE 2: Nope, it still wasn't fixed. The same problem occurred in the new profile as well, when I rebooted the PC.

Comment: Could you try to delete all the folders and files under this location? C:\Users\${UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code. And could you try to disable all the extensions except the Python extension?

Comment: Hope to hear from your response.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Hi, thank for your help. I had two other extensions installed and running, apart from the Python extension, which were Pylance and Jupyter extensions. I wanted to try and isolate the problem so I just disabled one extension, Jupyter in this case, first and test if it solved the problem and that seems to be the case right now. At least for now in the 2 reboots I've done, the problem hasn't occurred, which it was previously with the extension enabled. So thank you! I also didn't have to delete the content from that folder.

Comment: That's good, very glad to provide a little suggestion to help you solve the problem. have a good day : ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to delete all the folders and files under this location?

```
C:\Users\${UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code.
```

And could you try to disable all the extensions except the Python extension?